# how to calculate % progress based on two tables with where condition

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-query-builder, laravel-controller

What is the best way to calculate the % progress of the activity based on the completed activity task points and total activity task points at the same time get the total number of  activity task

I have two tables

```
activity and task
```

**Activity table**

```
id, name, title,
```

**Task table**

```
id, name, status('In progress','Completed), activity_id, points
```

**For Example**

Activity table has this data

| id | name | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.2.3 | Conduct Animation Settion |
| 2 | 1.3.2 | Adocacy session |

Task table has this data

| id | name | status | activity_id | points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | task 1 | Completed | 1 | 20 |
| 2 | task 2 | In Progress | 1 | 10 |
| 3 | task 3 | In Progress | 2 | 5 |
| 4 | task 4 | Completed | 1 | 8 |
| 5 | task 5 | Completed | 2 | 9 |

Expected output

**where % progress is calculated from total points of completed activity task and the total points of an activity task**

| id | name | title | task | total_task_points | total_completed_task_points | %progress |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.2.3 | Conduct Animation Settion | 3 | 38 | 28 | **(total_completed_task_points / total_task_points)x100** = 73.68% |
| 2 | 1.3.2 | Adocacy session | 2 | 14 | 9 | **(total_completed_task_points / total_task_points)x100** = 64.28% |

What I have tried

On Activity Controller

```
   public function index()
    {
        try {
            $activities = Activity::with('task')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
            return view('activities.index',compact('activities');
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $this->error('Page Not Found');
        }
    }
```

On view File

**percentage()** is a helper for % calculation

```
<table>
<thead>
   <th>id</th>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>title</th>
   <th>Task</th>
   <th>Points</th>
   <th>Progress</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach ($activities as $activity)
       <tr>
          <td class="text-center">{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
          <td class="text-start">{!! $activity->name !!} </td>
          <td class="text-start">{!! $activity->title !!} </td>
          <td  class="text-center">{!! $activity->task->count() !!}</td>
          <td  class="text-center">{!! $activity->task->sum('points') !!}</td>
          <td  class="text-center">
            <div class="progress">
               <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" 
                    style="width: {{percentage($activity->task->where('status','completed')->sum('points'),$activity->task->sum('points'))}}%"
                    aria-valuenow="{{percentage($activity->task->where('status','Completed')->sum('points'),$activity->task->sum('points'))}}"
                    aria-valuemin="0"
                    aria-valuemax="100">{{percentage($activity->task->where('status','Completed')->sum('points'),$activity->task->sum('points'))}}
                </div>
            </div>
          </td>
      </tr>
   @endforeach
</tbody>
```

As you can see on the view file is where all the calculations and filtering are done which is not a good practice. I need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doing logic inside blade view.

You can move your logic inside Model

at your Activity Model

```
class Activity extends Model
```

you can add the following code.

```
protected $appends = ['progress'];

public function getProgressAttribute(){
    return round(($this->completedPoints() / $this->totalPoints()) * 100, 2);
}

public function totalPoints(){
    return $this->task->sum('points');
}

public function completedPoints(){
    return $this->task->where("status", "Completed")->sum('points');
}
```

Then inside your blade view you can access to $activity->progress